# Binding scroll event - how to unbind?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am using the following code to bind scroll on a page;

```
angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function () {});
```

The issue I am having is that the binding is persisting when I navigate away from the page. How do I release a binding? I tried assigning it to a variable and calling said variable in the binding, like with `$on()` but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First namespace your scroll event, so you can remove it specifically when the need arises: `angular.element($window).bind("scroll.myScroll", function() {});`

Then unbind it:
`angular.element($window).unbind("scroll.myScroll");`

"myScroll" is a namespace you chose.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. What I've had to do to implement this practically is put the unbinding inside stateChangeStart within that page's controller, to remove the binding whenever the user leaves that page.